# How to add meta for users/%/posts views pages?

Tags: drupal, meta-tags, drupal-views

I have views pages with paths:

- `users/%/posts`
- `users/%/forum_topics`

How to add metatags for this pages? For example: "Posts created by Alex". Alex - user name.

Comment: Please be more specific question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

You can use Metatag Views Overview module  (https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag_views_overview) to add metatags in views pages.

Comment: It will providing the add metatag in view's pages, but if you review the hook_function of Metatag View Overview then you will get idea for add user's field to meta.